# Deck of cards implementation

Tags: java, object-oriented, playing-cards

**Update:** [Simple Blackjack implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97605/simple-blackjack-implementation)

I was playing Blackjack in a phone app and decided to try to do the game in Java, using the console for a start. So far I'd like to review the deck of cards implementation. I decided to use an OOP approach with the classes `Value`, `Suit`, `Card` and `Deck`.

First of all, I'd like to get some feedback and pieces of advice about how I decided to structure my code. Is there anything wrong? Should something be done differently?

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Blackjack {

    public static String capitalizeFully(String str) {
        String s = new String();

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            s += Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
        }

        return Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + s;
    }

    public static class Value {

        private int value;
        private static final String[] string_values = {
            "Ace",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
            "Ten",
            "Jack",
            "Queen",
            "King"
        };

        public Value(int value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if (value < 1 || value > 13) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid card value (must be between 1 and 13).");
            }
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Value(String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            int i = 0;
            String val = capitalizeFully(value);

            while (i < string_values.length && !val.equals(string_values[i])) {
                i++;
            }

            if (i == string_values.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid card value.");
            } else {
                this.value = i + 1;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return string_values[value - 1];
        }
    }

    public static class Suit {

        private String name;
        private static final String[] string_names = {
            "Hearts",
            "Diamonds",
            "Clubs",
            "Spades"
        };

        public Suit(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            int i = 0;
            String n = capitalizeFully(name);

            while (i < string_names.length && !n.equals(string_names[i])) {
                i++;
            }

            if (i == string_names.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid suit name.");
            } else {
                this.name = n;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static class Card {

        private Value value;
        private Suit suit;

        public Card(Value value, Suit suit) {
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public Card(int value, Suit suit) {
            this.value = new Value(value);
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public Card(String value, Suit suit) {
            this.value = new Value(value);
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public Card(Value value, String suit) {
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = new Suit(suit);
        }

        public Card(int value, String suit) {
            this.value = new Value(value);
            this.suit = new Suit(suit);
        }

        public Card(String value, String suit) {
            this.value = new Value(value);
            this.suit = new Suit(suit);
        }

        public String toString() {
            String str = value + " of " + suit;
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static class Deck {

        private Stack<Card> deck;
        private static final int number = 52;

        public Deck() {
            deck = new Stack<Card>();
            Suit hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades;

            hearts = new Suit("hearts");
            diamonds = new Suit("diamonds");
            clubs = new Suit("clubs");
            spades = new Suit("spades");

            Suit[] suits = { hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades };

            for (int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
                    deck.push(new Card(j, suits[i]));
                }
            }
        }

        public void shuffle() {
            long seed = System.nanoTime();
            Collections.shuffle(deck, new Random(seed));
        }

        public void add(Card card) {
            deck.push(card);
        }

        public Card draw() {
            return deck.pop();
        } 

        public String toString() {
            String str = new String();
            for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++) {
                str += deck.get(i) + "\n";
            }
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static <T> void p(T output) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
        p(deck);
    }
}
```

However, this is an implementation for just the 52-card standard deck. How about different decks, with different suits and a different range of values? I thought maybe it'd be a good idea that instead of hardcoding these attributes, I could make an alternative implementation where the user can define his/her own set of suits and range of values, so the deck is constructed given these set of choices.

For example:

```
Value[] values = { new Value("As", 1), new Value("Dos", 2), ..., new Value("Rey", 12) };
Suit[] suits = { new Suit("Oros"), new Suit("Sotas"), new Suit("Espadas"), new Suit("Bastos") };

Deck spanish_deck = new Deck(suits, values);
```

Does this second alternative make sense? Is it a good approach?

**Update:** [Simple Blackjack implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97605/simple-blackjack-implementation)

Comment: As for the "second alternative": I think it's a good idea. You could overload the constructor for deck maybe? Without params it uses the default 1-13, Hearts Diamonds Spades Clubs values, else it makes a deck of any combination of values and suits that you put in to it. I'd be interested in seeing your blackjack implementation too, as it's something I've attempted before

Comment: check out my update

Answer (score 3):

For starters, using [Java `enum`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) will likely save you a lot of the boilerplate-like template code you have for `Value` and `Suit`.

Your `Card` constructors seem to be over-engineered too... what you have are just permutations of `int`s, `String`s *and* objects arguments... I suggest you pick one and stick with that, preferably just `Value` and `Suit`. If your `Card` objects are meant to be immutable, I'll suggest saving its `String` representation (used, naturally, in `toString()`) as an instance field first. In fact, you should probably go a step further and override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods too to simplify/standardize such usage for the class. This will be helpful if you are using them in most, if not all, `Collection` classes.

Unfortunately, your implementation for `capitalizeFully()` doesn't seem too good... First, I'm not sure what it's meant by 'fully' capitalizing a `String`. I thought you meant converting a `String` to uppercase. Turns out you are just capitalizing the first letter. So why not call that then?

```
private static String capitalizeFirstLetter(String input) {
    // ...
}
```

Unless you are constructing `String`s from `byte`/`char` arrays, with an optional [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), you should (almost) never need to instantiate a `String` by doing `new String()`. Then, using the [`toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) and [`toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) methods...

```
private static String capitalizeFirstLetter(String input) {
    // handle null or "" Strings if required
    return input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

If you want to cater for [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)-specific conversions, there are methods for that too.

Last, you need a *much better* name for your print (?) `p()` method... what is it supposed to do actually? The returned object doesn't appear to be used in any way.

**edit** further explanation for an `enum`-approach

Say you have a `Rank` and `Suit` `enum`:

```
enum Rank {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    // ...
    JACK,
    QUEEN,
    KING,
    ACE; // opt-ing to 'rank' ACE as the highest

    public int getValue() {
        return ordinal() + 1;
    }
}

enum Suit {
    CLUB,
    DIAMOND,
    HEART,
    SPADE;
}
```

Some benefits of using `enum`s are:

- Values are `Comparable` to each other.
- Efficient use in `Map`s and `Set`s via [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) and [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) classes, when required.
- built-in [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) representation.
- built-in index-based lookup for values via [`ordinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--).
- built-in `String`-based lookup for values via [`valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-).
- safe `==`-based comparison.

For your `Card` class, you can then do something like:

```
// note: final modifier to indicate this class cannot be subclassed
// in order to preserve the immutable features
public final class Card {
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private final String toString;
    private final int hashCode;

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.toString = getToString(rank, suit);
        // Objects.hash() is from Java 7
        this.hashCode = Objects.hash(rank, suit);
    }

    private static String getToString(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        // code review comment: will return e.g. "Seven of Hearts"
        return String.format("%s of %ss",
                    capitalizeFirstLetter(rank.toString()),
                    capitalizeFirstLetter(suit.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Card)) {
            return false;
        }
        Card otherCard = (Card) o;
        return otherCard.rank == rank && otherCard.suit == suit;
    }
}
```

I hope this kind of illustrates that your `Value`/`Rank`, `Suit` and `Card` classes can have similar functionality with less boilerplate-like template code... The idea behind pre-computing the `String` representation and hash code first is to avoid repeated computations, should the methods be called frequently. This works especially well for immutable classes like the `Card` class as shown.

Comment: `p()` is just for printing, when I am using Java it's very annoying for me to have to write `System.out.println()` again and again, which is pretty long. The returning type is not necessary, I shall remove it. I turned `Suit` and `Value` into classes (they were `enum`originally) to avoid delegating the responsability of checking correct attributes to the `Card`class, as well as hardcoding the available choices. I don't understand what you mean with the part where you say if my `Card` objects are mean to me immutable until the end of the paragraph.

Comment: Wells, I guess you can configure your IDE with a keyboard shortcut for `System.out.println()`... can you explain what you mean by 'checking correct attributes to the `Card` class'?

Comment: What I mean I am throwing exceptions in the `Suit` and `Value` classes, as well as creating different constructors, attributes and the `toString()` method. I am not using an IDE, just Sublime.

Comment: immutability means a `Card` object will not have its suit or value (actually, the proper 'card' term is [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_card_game_terms#R)) changed after instantiation. This reduces the chances of concurrent modification (leading to invalidated results) when used in a multi-threaded context.

Comment: So you mean that if `Card` is immutable I should probably get rid of the `Suit` and `Value` classes and turn them into `Card`'s `String` attributes? Could you explain what you mean by then overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: oh and to correct myself, `p()` doesn't have a return type, it is `void`

Comment: @dabadaba see updated answer.